# Mimic C++ in java structure and writing to byte[]

Tags: java, c++, structure, marshalling

I am porting some C++ code over to java, and in my particular instance, i am writing data to a byte[] to be written to a file.  The first portion, as defined in C++ is a structure consisting of a uint, and 3 ushorts.  The second portion is the main part of the data, which i will just append on the end of the byte[] before i send it to the outputstream.

My question is this:  What is the simplest way to write the header values to the byte[]?  I know i can put 1 value in there, then offset the specific number of bytes, and repeat as necessary, but is this the best way to do it?

Also, how do i manage byte alignment?  The C++ code appears to use the default values (4-byte?) for alignment.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: To begin with, Java has no unsigned types. You are in for some heavy bit-fiddling.

Comment: There are ways to treat Java types as unsigned, but they require being very careful not to mix up the values.

Comment: You can write unsigned values as if they were signed. Usually a cast is all you need at most.

Comment: in looking at the data, i have determined that the 3 ushorts don't have to be unsigned.  The only one that i am concerned about is the uint, which represents a time.  it is the result of calling _ftime_s, and then grabbing the .time out of the timebuffer. the .time appears to be time_t, and indicates it is a signed int.  I dont' know why the code we have converts it to a unsigned int.  Oddly enough, i see that we cast the value before it is stored in the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find it easier to use [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), which is probably the nicest way in Java to organize byte-by-byte output.

`ByteBuffer` doesn't directly care about alignment, though, and I don't know how C++ is aligning its output -- but in a pinch, you can just advance it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DataOutputStream that wraps a ByteArrayOutputStream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

try {
    stream.writeInt(i);
    stream.writeShort(s0);
    stream.writeShort(s1);
    stream.writeShort(s2);
    stream.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // this can't happen, but you still require a try catch block
}

byte[] array = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

If your code might be parsing a similar byte array with unsigned integers then you're going to have a bit of headache. That is, you will have to check for negative numbers and deal with them appropriately.
eg.

```
int unsignedIntAsSignedInt = inStream.readInt();
long realData;
if (unsignedIntAsSignedInt < 0) {
    realData = ((long) unsignedIntAsSignedInt) - (((long)Integer.MIN_VALUE) * 2);
} else {
    realData = unsignedIntAsSignedInt;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work as i was working on a windows machine.  I needed to be able to set the endian-ness to LITTLE_ENDIAN when writing the data out.